# A generator of a cyclic subgroup of a group fixes every coset of the generated aubgroup into itself,H is normal

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group.H be a cyclic subgroup of G generated by an element g in G.If the left multiplication by g fixes every coset of H in G,show that H is normal in G.

Comment: if you multiply the generator of H to H, you get H itself. If you multiply H with every element in the group, you get all the cosets, and this is true of any subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**

> You are assuming that for all $x \in G$ you have$$g x H = x H,$$

**Hint 2**

> This is equivalent to$$x^{-1} g x H = H.$$

**Hint 3**

> This is equivalent to$$x^{-1} g x \in H.$$

Comment: @lhf, right, thanks a lot! My generous spacing habits in Latex code led to a mistake this time.